# How to catch com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The query has timed out

Tags: java, sql-server, exception, try-catch, timeoutexception

I am having some of the stored procedures in the MS-SQL and I wanted to do certain piece of codes in case of timeout issue. I have done a few things which I want to share:

```
catch (Exception e) {
boolean bool = e.getClass().equals(SQLServerException.class);
  if(bool){
  //-- My piece of code logic
 }
}
```

My problem is, I want to do my piece of code in case of only

```
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The query has timed out
```

How to catch that particular timeout exception?

Comment: `catch (SQLServerException e) {` or even `catch (SQLException e) {`

Comment: but `SQLServerExcpetion` could be of any type, such as `timeout`,  `closed connection` , `login failed for user` etc... How to catch particularly `timeout` issue?

Comment: It's still a `SQLServerException`. You'll have to catch it and parse the error code or the message to catch a particular issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just got a solution which solved my problem:

```
catch(Exception e){
 boolean bool = e.getMessage().contains("The query has timed out");
 if(bool){
   //-- My piece of code logic
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***case*** to check the error code in the exception.

```
catch (SQLException se) {
        switch (se.getErrorCode()) {
        case 1:  doSomething();
            break;
        case 2:  doSomethingElse();
            break;
    }
}
```

The list of the error codes is here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-develop-error-messages